# Droidgap vs CordovaWebView

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am new to Phonegap and I need to clear some doubts for my next app on Android for which I am going to use Phonegap 2.0.0.

Would it be better to use the legacy approach of extending the DroidGap class or rather follow the new approach of using the CordovaWebView.

I read [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/CordovaWebView) that the DroidGap class will be deprecated and CordovaWebView is further improved for tweaking performance.

I want a non-laggy app and most of current Phonegap apps do lag a bit if compared to their native versions. 
So what should I prefer?

Forgive if this question is too stupid to be asked ..

Comment: Obviously if the `DroidGap` class will be deprecated, I would use the brand new `CordovaWebView` as it's support will be longer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the DroidGap approach is the quickest and easiest to get up and running. I suspect this class will be around for some time yet. Even if it does go away you will always be able to use an older version of PhoneGap/Cordova or grab the source for DroidGap and include it in your own application.

If you need to embedded your CordovaWebView in a bigger Android application than that is the class to start with.